# Caliburn.Micro actions don't work properly

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I have a problem with defining actions using Caliburn.Micro in my xaml file (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1).

namespaces:

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Method 1.

```
<Button Content="TEST" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="test" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Method 2.

```
<Button Content="TEST" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action test]"/>
```

Both methods give me errors:

- Error    1   The attachable property 'Attach' was not found in type
  'Message'.
- Error    2   The name "Message" does not exist in the namespace
  "clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro".
- Error    3   The    property 'Attach' does not exist on the type 'Button'
  in the XML    namespace
  'clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro'.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.
Damian

Comment: can you show us some bootstrapper code w/respect to Configure and viewmodel code w/respect to how you coded up your Test method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try use `xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"` you are probably using the latest Csliburn.Micro version. Read about it on http://wp.qmatteoq.com/porting-a-windows-phone-8-0-application-to-caliburn-micro-2-0-2/